# On what platforms will this crash, and how can I improve it?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic, struct

I've written the rudiments of a class for creating dynamic structures in C++. Dynamic structure members are stored contiguously with (as far as my tests indicate) the same padding that the compiler would insert in the equivalent static structure. Dynamic structures can thus be implicitly converted to static structures for interoperability with existing APIs.

Foremost, I don't trust myself to be able to write Boost-quality code that can compile and work on more or less any platform. What parts of this code are dangerously in need of modification?

I have one other design-related question: Is a templated `get` accessor the only way of providing the compiler with the requisite static type information for type-safe code? As it is, the user of `dynamic_struct` must specify the type of the member they are accessing, whenever they access it. If that type should change, *all* of the accesses become invalid, and will either cause spectacular crashes—or worse, fail silently. And it can't be caught at compile time. That's a huge risk, and one I'd like to remedy.

Example of usage:

```
struct Test {

    char a, b, c;
    int i;
    Foo object;

};

void bar(const Test&);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    dynamic_struct<std::string> ds(sizeof(Test));

    ds.append<char>("a") = 'A';
    ds.append<char>("b") = '2';
    ds.append<char>("c") = 'D';
    ds.append<int>("i") = 123;
    ds.append<Foo>("object");
    bar(ds);

}
```

And the code follows:

```
//
// dynamic_struct.h
//
// Much omitted for brevity.
//


/**
 * For any type, determines the alignment imposed by the compiler.
 */
template<class T>
class alignment_of {
private:

    struct alignment {

        char a;
        T b;

    }; // struct alignment

public:

    enum { value = sizeof(alignment) - sizeof(T) };

}; // class alignment_of


/**
 * A dynamically-created structure, whose fields are indexed by keys of
 * some type K, which can be substituted at runtime for any structure
 * with identical members and packing.
 */
template<class K>
class dynamic_struct {
public:


    // Default maximum structure size.
    static const int DEFAULT_SIZE = 32;


    /**
     * Create a structure with normal inter-element padding.
     */
    dynamic_struct(int size = DEFAULT_SIZE) : max(size) {

        data.reserve(max);

    } // dynamic_struct()


    /**
     * Copy structure from another structure with the same key type.
     */
    dynamic_struct(const dynamic_struct& structure) :
        members(structure.members), max(structure.max) {

        data.reserve(max);

        for (iterator i = members.begin(); i != members.end(); ++i)
            i->second.copy(&data[0] + i->second.offset,
                &structure.data[0] + i->second.offset);

    } // dynamic_struct()


    /**
     * Destroy all members of the structure.
     */
    ~dynamic_struct() {

        for (iterator i = members.begin(); i != members.end(); ++i)
            i->second.destroy(&data[0] + i->second.offset);

    } // ~dynamic_struct()


    /**
     * Get a value from the structure by its key.
     */
    template<class T>
    T& get(const K& key) {

        iterator i = members.find(key);

        if (i == members.end()) {

            std::ostringstream message;
            message << "Read of nonexistent member \"" << key << "\".";
            throw dynamic_struct_access_error(message.str());

        } // if

        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0] + i->second.offset.offset);

    } // get()


    /**
     * Append a member to the structure.
     */
    template<class T>
    T& append(const K& key, int alignment = alignment_of<T>::value) {

        iterator i = members.find(key);

        if (i != members.end()) {

            std::ostringstream message;
            message << "Add of already existing member \"" << key << "\".";
            throw dynamic_struct_access_error(message.str());

        } // if

        const int modulus = data.size() % alignment;
        const int delta = modulus == 0 ? 0 : sizeof(T) - modulus;

        if (data.size() + delta + sizeof(T) > max) {

            std::ostringstream message;

            message << "Attempt to add " << delta + sizeof(T)
                << " bytes to struct, exceeding maximum size of "
                << max << ".";

            throw dynamic_struct_size_error(message.str());

        } // if

        data.resize(data.size() + delta + sizeof(T));

        new (static_cast<void*>(&data[0] + data.size() - sizeof(T))) T;

        std::pair<iterator, bool> j = members.insert
            ({key, member(data.size() - sizeof(T), destroy<T>, copy<T>)});

        if (j.second) {

            return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0] + j.first->second.offset);

        } else {

            std::ostringstream message;
            message << "Unable to add member \"" << key << "\".";
            throw dynamic_struct_access_error(message.str());

        } // if

    } // append()


    /**
     * Implicit checked conversion operator.
     */
    template<class T>
    operator T&() { return as<T>(); }


    /**
     * Convert from structure to real structure.
     */
    template<class T>
    T& as() {

        // This naturally fails more frequently if changed to "!=".
        if (sizeof(T) < data.size()) {

            std::ostringstream message;

            message << "Attempt to cast dynamic struct of size "
                << data.size() << " to type of size " << sizeof(T) << ".";

            throw dynamic_struct_size_error(message.str());

        } // if

        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[0]);

    } // as()


private:


    // Map from keys to member offsets.
    map_type members;

    // Data buffer.
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;

    // Maximum allowed size.
    const unsigned int max;


}; // class dynamic_struct
```

Comment: I take it the vote to close is because SO is not responsible for peer-reviewing my code, and any question containing code that requires scrolling automatically gets a downvote. Ah, well.

Comment: What about writing this up as an article on CodeProject? Or, if it doesn't get closed here (having it closed would be an unfortunate outcome IMHO) then you or someone else could attach a bounty to it.

Comment: Yeah, I may just have to seek alternate venues, though I was already considering adding a bounty, and if any interest remains in the question, I certainly will.

Comment: In my opinion, he's got a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @DeadMG: Presentation is everything, though, and this is a rather, ah, *sensitive* site due to all of the abuses and facepalm-inducing tomfoolery that goes on. It's no great wonder people are a little on edge about imperfect questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with this kind of code. Delaying type-checking until runtime is perfectly valid, although you will have to work hard to defeat the compile-time type system. I wrote a homogenous stack class, where you could insert any type, which functioned in a similar fashion.

However, you have to ask yourself- what are you actually going to be using this for? I wrote a homogenous stack to replace the C++ stack for an interpreted language, which is a pretty tall order for any particular class. If you're not doing something drastic, this probably isn't the right thing to do.

In short, you can do it, and it's not illegal or bad or undefined and you can make it work - but you only should if you have a very desperate need to do things outside the normal language scope. Also, your code will die horrendously when C++0x becomes Standard and now you need to move and all the rest of it.

The easiest way to think of your code is actually a managed heap of a miniature size. You place on various types of object.. they're stored contiguously, etc.

Edit: Wait, you didn't manage to enforce type safety at runtime either? You just blew compile-time type safety but didn't replace it? Let me post some far superior code (that is somewhat slower, probably).

Edit: Oh wait. You want to convert your dynamic_struct, as the whole thing, to arbitrary unknown other structs, at runtime? Oh. Oh, man. Oh, seriously. What. Just no. Just don't. Really, really, don't. That's so wrong, it's unbelievable. If you had reflection, you could make this work, but C++ doesn't offer that. You can enforce type safety at runtime per each individual member using dynamic_cast and type erasure with inheritance. Not for the whole struct, because given a type T you can't tell what the types or binary layout is.

Comment: This has been yet another exercise in circumventing C++ to be more like the language I'm writing, because I'm much too lazy to actually just *work* on the language. Honestly. Anyway, one of the supposed advantages of something like this class is that it could be used to make automatic conversions simpler between structures that are semantically compatible but not binary-compatible, which I guess would be a boon when mixing old C APIs.

Comment: How would it help? You can only convert at the binary level. It would be easier to write your own cast operators - they don't have to be members, you know.

Comment: Yeah, type safety considerations gone out the window; very bad. I guess the simplest way to take care of it it to just store and test the `typeid` result for each member. Unchecked accesses would then be equivalent to plain old `reinterpret_cast`, if you happen to need that.

Comment: No. For each individual member, you can use inheritance and dynamic_cast to enforce type safety. What you can't do is support casting the dynamic_struct itself to any arbitrary type, as C++ won't give you enough information about T to tell if you can safely convert or not.

Comment: Simply having the ability to dynamically create structures that are binary-compatible with static structures could be useful enough. And how do I get `dynamic_cast` to play nice with POD members?

Comment: Write your own linked list class. For the nodes, inherit from base class, typename T. Store index into memory buffer in derived class. Map key type to base_node*. When accessing, dynamic_cast the resulting pointer to derived_node<T>*. If dynamic_cast succeeds, the memory at memory_buffer[ptr] is of type T, and you can guarantee the safety of the following static cast. Else, throw exception, because that's not the right type. Of course, this can be optimized much further if you know what you're doing. This can be expanded to form all necessary accesses, copy, destruct, etc.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Well, there's the type safety issue more or less solved. Now, if I can just make sure the alignment isn't going to bite me later...

Comment: @Jon Purdy: It's not solved. That technique only works per member. You can't guarantee anything at all about converting the whole struct, because C++ doesn't provide the necessary compile-time or run-time reflection you'd need to determine if it's safe or not.

Comment: @DeadMG: C++ doesn't provide it, but @Potatoswatter's answer does, at least as well as can be hoped for.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: If you're going to manually write code for every potential struct, why not just write your own cast operator?

Answer (score 1):

I think the type-checking could be improved. Right now it will `reinterpret_cast` itself to any type with the same size.

Maybe create an interface to register client structures at program startup, so they may be verified member-by-member — or even rearranged on the fly, or constructed more intelligently in the first place.

```
#define REGISTER_DYNAMIC_STRUCT_CLIENT( STRUCT, MEMBER ) \
    do dynamic_struct::registry< STRUCT >() // one registry obj per client type \
        .add( # MEMBER, &STRUCT::MEMBER, offsetof( STRUCT, MEMBER ) ) while(0)
        //    ^ name as str ^ ptr to memb ^ check against dynamic offset
```

Comment: I was just thinking about macro-based solutions to this, myself, and yours is rather a good approach. It would involve separating the *description* of a `dynamic_struct` from the *instance*, but that was something that needed to be done anyway.

Comment: @Jon: No separation needs to occur at all… I was thinking that the `as` method, once it knows the destination of the cast, would consult the registry. Maybe reference-counted smart pointers could achieve partial separation, and the best of both worlds.

Comment: My thoughts exactly: you've mistaken my meaning. As it stands, the `members` member of the `dynamic_struct` is, well, a member. It should be living statically in the registry and shared between `dynamic_struct` instances. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I have one question: what do you get out of it ?

I mean it's a clever piece of code but:

- you're fiddling with memory, the chances of blow-up are huge
- it's quite complicated too, I didn't get everything and I would certainly have to pose longer...

What I am really wondering is what you actually want...

For example, using [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html)

```
struct a_key { typedef char type; };
struct object_key { typedef Foo type; };

typedef boost::fusion<
  std::pair<a_key, a_key::type>,
  std::pair<object_key, object_key::type>
> data_type;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  data_type data;
  boost::fusion::at_key<a_key>(data) = 'a'; // compile time checked
}
```

Using Boost.Fusion you get compile-time reflection as well as correct packing.

I don't really see the need for "runtime" selection here (using a value as key instead of a type) when you need to pass the right type to the assignment anyway (`char` vs `Foo`).

Finally, note that this can be automated, thanks to preprocessor programming:

```
DECLARE_ATTRIBUTES(
  mData,
  (char, a)
  (char, b)
  (char, c)
  (int, i)
  (Foo, object)
)
```

Not much wordy than a typical declaration, though `a`, `b`, etc... will be inner types rather than attributes names.

This has several advantages over your solution:

- compile-time checking
- perfect compliance with default generated constructors / copy constructors / etc...
- much more compact representation
- no runtime lookup of the "right" member